# Using Scipy.optimize method='SLSQP' returns initial guess

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

I try to dig more into optimization of functions depending on multiple variables with scipy

I have a function returning prediction from a data mining tool after calling this tool with a batch file.

```
def query(x):
    import numpy as np
    file_direc_in="path_to_input_file.csv"
    file_direc_out="path_to_output_file.csv"


    with open(file_direc_in, 'w') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, x, delimiter=';', fmt='%.3f',newline='\r\n')
    f.close()
    os.system("Dataset_query.bat")
    #batch file takes the array i wrote to from input_file and estimates a result
    #afterwards the output will be taken from the output file:
    f = open(file_direc_out,'r')
    out = np.array([[float(f.readlines()[0])]])
    f.close()
    return out


from scipy.optimize import minimize
from calc import query
import numpy as np

x0=np.array([[1.5,50,30]])

bnds = ((1, 2), (0.1, 100), (20, 100))

res=minimize(query,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds, options={'maxiter': 10 , 'disp': True}, callback=True)
```

when I run the script I see the loop in my console, but it seems that there aren´t really values tested for my variables and I get the initial guess returned:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [[ 1636.724]]
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 5
            Gradient evaluations: 1
```

although I know that for this problem the minimum lies at `x_minimum=[1,0.1,100]`
with a value of out at about `out=400`
( i have to decrease the first and second value of the variable and increase the third value to get a lower `out`)

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going wrong without knowing what `Dataset_query.bat` (which, by the way, needs to be in quotes for the `os.system()` call) does. A couple of other side points: you should do your module imports at the top of the file, definitely not inside a function (unless you have a very good reason to). I would also pass extra args such as `file_direc_in` to `minimize` using `args=()`.

Comment: Another thought just occurred to me. When you write out your updated version of `x` in `query(x)`, you truncate it to 3 decimal places. If `minimize` makes only a very small change to one of the parameters, this change won't be carried forward to `Dataset_query.bat` where you actually compute the loss. Therefore, when `minimize` estimates the partial derivatives of `query(x)` w.r.t. `x` by finite differences, if the step size is sufficiently small it might incorrectly estimate the gradient as 0 so the optimization doesn't progress. Try writing `x` out to, say, 10 decimal places instead.

Comment: Do you mean something like:  `x0=np.array([[1.50000000,50.00000000,30.00000000]])` ? Imagine the Batch file calls the DM program to return an estimation for the given input vextor `x`.Many "measured" datasets with the same shape as the input `x` vector were used to determine the best estimator. If it was a Multiple Regression i could extract it as a function and also determine the derivative of it... but it is not so easy - I guess i cannot determine an algebraic equation in my case because the estimator could also be A _Support Vector Regression_ or some other tool used in Machine Learning.

Comment: I still don't totally understand what you're trying to do. Could you give me a bit of information about the problem you're trying to solve? If I understand correctly, `file_direc_out` contains the result of some function *yhat = f(x)*. You need `query` to return a scalar *l = g(f(x))* that you want to minimize over *x*. For example, for fitting problems you'd often use the sum of squared errors *l = sum((y - yhat)^2)*.

Comment: I followed your advice (which i think is really good!) about the precision and set it to `fmt='%.20f'` and i look by typing `res.x` (or in my last csv input file) after running  the optimization script, you seem to be right: np.array([[1.50000000000000000000;50.00000000000000000000;30.00000001000000082740]]) Can i tell the algorithm to increase the steps ? I thought of using another algorithm but for my problems i need to be able to set bounds and constraints..Looking in the docs [scipydoc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#id8)only 'SLSQP' is ok.

Comment: Forget about step sizes for the time being. I still think you're misunderstanding what `query()` needs to return - see my last comment.

Comment: yes the variable `out` holds the value or let us say _yhat_ after each call with `x` but I do not know what `y` really is!... what i want is find the right combination for my inputs x[0],x[1] and x[2] which are the elements of `x` and minimize the `out` (_yhat_). for this easy problem i know that to minimize the _yhat_ I have to increase x[2] (_yhat_ is monotonically nonincreasing with x[2]) the other two variables have the opposite dependencies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44117/discussion-between-ali-m-and-user2956831)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Solution in my case was changing the step size, because of the unsmoothness of my prediction function `query`

```
res=minimize(query,args=(hist,ana),x0=x0,method='SLSQP',/
bounds=bnds, options={'disp': True ,'eps' : 1e0})
```

In my case searching for local minima does not make sense and I am now searching in integer steps for the minima.

according to @ali_m searching for a global minimum `basinhopping` could be used instead.
I will give it a try in the next days